# Stacking two 3D numpy arrays along the median of the z-axis and keep the size of the smaller array

Tags: python, image, numpy, stack, concatenation

I want to stack two sets of images (im-series1 = 32x32x16 and im_series2 = 32x32x21) based on the median of the z axis and keep the adjacent values with respect to the shape of im-series1 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2kAV.jpg).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is first crop im_series2, and then stack. Note that there are two ways to crop im_series to fit im_series1, both are "median".

```
import numpy as np
im_series2 = np.ones((32, 32, n)) # this is im_series2 as an example
mid = n // 2
im_series2 = im_series2[:, :, mid-8:mid+8] # this is the cropping. [:,:,2:-3] is also valid
print(im_series2.shape)
im_series1 = np.ones((32, 32, 16)) # this is im_series1 as an example
print(im_series1 .shape)
c = np.concatenate((im_series1 , im_series2), axis=-1) # this concatenates them on the z_axis
print(c.shape)
```

This outputs:

```
(32, 32, 16)
(32, 32, 16)
(32, 32, 32)
```

Comment: Thank you is there are more general way to do this for stacks of images? Something like im_series1(32x32x16), im_series2 (32x32x21), im_series3 (32x32x26), ... ->im_series1(32x32x16), im_series2 (32x32x16), im_series3 (32x32x16), ...

Comment: You noticed that there are two ways to crop `im_series2` (see my comment in the third line), are both ok?  In your more general case, can I assume that the last channel is always in the form of  `16 + 5 * x`, i.e 16,26,31,36,41... ?

Comment: they both work for this example. No the last channel is of arbitrary length. Ideally I want a function that takes the median of the last channel and extends it by some number in both ways.

Comment: ok, see my edited answer. This dhould work for the general case too. If it solves your question, mark it as such :)